# REST APIs atomic?

Tags: rest, concurrency, jersey, atomic

I would like to know the importance of ensuring atomicity in rest api's.

Say suppose there exists a REST API

```
   insertItems(List<String> items)
```

**Should we design API such that all items are inserted or none ? (atomic)**

Example : Sa¥ suppose we tried to insert 10 items, and received error while inserting 5th item, we revoke all the 4 items inserted. (To make sure as if none were inserted) and return back to caller that API call failed.

OR

**Return the items which were inserted successfully such that client can handle with failed items ?**

Example : SaY suppose we tried to insert 10 items, and received error while inserting 5th item, we return list of 4 items that were inserted successfully to caller. This leads caller to process the returned list and analyze what items were failed or etc. This involves burden on client side to deal with analysis.

Do you guys have any strong opinion on either cases ? What is ideal to use and under what circumstances ?

Comment: This appears to be purely an opinion based question. In my opinion, atomic behavior is the least surprising and easiest to reason about behaviors as a consumer. There are specific cases, however, where the functionality of individual items succeeding and failing independently is needed.